# Electromagnet attracting permanent magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, magnetic-monopoles

Permanent magnet gets attracted to electromagnets iron core ,but if we energize electromagnet for attraction force will it attract strongly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Electromagnets are magnets, so of course it will attract. Whether it will attract "strongly" depends on what you mean by "strongly".

Comment: Permanent magnet will stick to iron without powering it on but if we power it will it attract strongly then its being off

Comment: I think OP is asking if the attraction is stronger if you replace the hunk of iron with another magnet.

Comment: I think that it would matter how much power is being used in the elector magnet and the direction of magnetization. If there is more pull force from the magnet to the iron core than the electromagnet then it shouldn't really change the amount of force.

Comment: If core of electromagnet is saturated by permanent magnet will it attract strongly if we power it on ?